# Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name Internationalisation/StatsBundle, locale en_US

Tags: java, internationalization

I'm currently studying Internationalisation at Java tutorial Oracle. When I'm trying to run the code below, the IDE always display the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name Internationalisation/StatsBundle, locale en_US
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1564)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1387)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:845)
    at Internationalisation.ListDemo.displayValues(ListDemo.java:20)
    at Internationalisation.ListDemo.main(ListDemo.java:41)
Java Result: 1
```

Here is my code:

```
public class ListDemo {

   static void displayValues(Locale currentLocale) {

      ResourceBundle stats = 
         ResourceBundle.getBundle("Internationalisation/StatsBundle",currentLocale);

      Integer gdp = (Integer)stats.getObject("GDP");
      System.out.println("GDP = " + gdp.toString());
      Integer pop = (Integer)stats.getObject("Population");
      System.out.println("Population = " + pop.toString());
      Double lit = (Double)stats.getObject("Literacy");
      System.out.println("Literacy = " + lit.toString());

   } // displayValues

   static public void main(String[] args) {

      Locale[] supportedLocales = {
         new Locale("en", "US"),
         new Locale("ja","JP"),
         new Locale("fr","FR")
      };

      for (int i = 0; i < supportedLocales.length; i ++) {
         System.out.println("Locale = " + supportedLocales[i]);
         displayValues(supportedLocales[i]);
         System.out.println();
      }

   } // main

} // class
```

[image]

Comment: How are you including your dependencies and building your project?

Comment: i'm very sorry, but i'm relatively new to java so i'm not sure what you mean by including dependencies :(

Comment: could you please kindly explain it to me? Thank you very much!